# Resize multiple layers around their respective anchor points

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, resize

I have 50 or so layers (imported images as smart objects) that I would like to scale down, while they stay in place. Is there a way of doing this? I know After Effects has, is there a similar Scale property in photoshop?

Comment: Regretfully, I do not think it's possible. (InDesign does it.... but PS does not - drives me nuts!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeking is a "Transform Each" function. Photoshop simply does not offer this ability. Adobe Illustrator does if that is an option.

Answer (score 16):

### [Transform Each 2.1](https://blog.darkwark.com/transformEach21/) script

[image]
[image]

For preservation, here's the code:

[[KAM] Transform Each 2.1.jsx](https://blog.darkwark.com/transformEach21/):

```
@JSXBIN@ES@2.0@MyBbyBnAEM2hRBbyBn0ABa2hSBb2hTBn0AEJ2hTBnAEjzRjNjBjLjFiBjDjUjJjWj
FiCjZiJjOjEjFjYBfRCARBQzACfVzOjTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEiMjBjZjFjSjTDfBVzBjJEfAfFcfffJ2hV
BnAEXzGjSjFjTjJjajFFfXzLjBjDjUjJjWjFiMjBjZjFjSGfXzOjBjDjUjJjWjFiEjPjDjVjNjFjOjU
HfjzDjBjQjQIfRDVzKjIjPjSjJjajPjOjUjBjMJfCVzIjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjMKfDVzOjBjOjDjIjPjSi
QjPjTjJjUjJjPjOLfGffJ2hWBnAEXzGjSjPjUjBjUjFMfXGfXHfjIfRCVzFjBjOjHjMjFNfEVLfGffO
2hYBby2hZBn0ABJ2hZBnAEjzLjTjDjBjMjFiTjUjZjMjFjTOfRBEXzDjNjBjYPfjzEiNjBjUjIQfRCX
zFjWjBjMjVjFRfjzNjIjPjSjJjajPjOjUjBjMifjTjMSfXRfjzLjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjMifjTjMTfffff
AVzHjTjDjBjMjFiGiYUfFnAVEf0AXzGjMjFjOjHjUjIVfVDfBByBzBhcWAHE40BiAN4D0AhAU4E0AhA
L4F0AhAD40BhAJ4B0AhAK4C0AhAGBAzNjUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNiFjBjDjIXA2hcBM2heBbyBn0ABg2i
ABbyBn0AGJ2iCBnASzTjJjEjTjDjBjMjFiFjGjGjFjDjUjTiFjWjFjOjUYAEjzQjTjUjSjJjOjHiJiE
iUjPiUjZjQjFiJiEZfRBFeRjTjDjBjMjFiFjGjGjFjDjUjTiFjWjFjOjUffnftJ2iDBnASzHjEjFjTj
DhRhShRgaBEjzQiBjDjUjJjPjOiEjFjTjDjSjJjQjUjPjSgbfntnftJ2iEBnASzFjJjEiTjDjMgcCEj
zOjDjIjBjSiJiEiUjPiUjZjQjFiJiEgdfRBFeEiTjDjMhAffnftJ2iFBnASzFjJjEiQjSjDgeDEjgdf
RBFeEhDiQjSjDffnftJ2iGBnAEXzNjQjVjUiVjOjJjUiEjPjVjCjMjFgffVgafBRDVgcfCVgefDVzHj
QjFjSjDjFjOjUhAfEffJ2iHBnAEjzNjFjYjFjDjVjUjFiBjDjUjJjPjOhBfRDVYfAVgafBXzCiOiPhC
fjzLiEjJjBjMjPjHiNjPjEjFjThDfffABnzBjFhEnnAFhA40BhAY40BiAga4B0AiAgc4C0AiAge4D0A
iABEAOA2iLBM2iRBbyBn0AGJ2iWBnASDAEjzFiBjSjSjBjZhFfntnftJ2iXBnASzDjSjFjGhGBEjzPi
BjDjUjJjPjOiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFhHfntnftJ2iYBnAEXzNjQjVjUiFjOjVjNjFjSjBjUjFjEhIfVh
GfBRDEjgdfRBFeEiEjDjNjOffEjgdfRBFeEiPjSjEjOffEjgdfRBFeEiUjSjHjUffffJ2iaBnASzEjE
jFjTjDhJCEjzQjFjYjFjDjVjUjFiBjDjUjJjPjOiHjFjUhKfRBVhGfBffnftO2ibBb2icBn0AEJ2icB
nAShJCEXzHjHjFjUiMjJjTjUhLfVhJfCRBEjZfRBFeMjUjBjSjHjFjUiMjBjZjFjSjTffffnffJ2idB
nASzBjDhMDXzFjDjPjVjOjUhNfVhJfCnftJ2ieBnASDAEjhFfntnfta2ifBby2jABn0ABg2jABbyBn0
ACJ2jBBnAXzPjCjBjDjLjHjSjPjVjOjEiMjBjZjFjShOfjHfJ2jCBnAEXzEjQjVjTjIhPfVDfARBEXz
IjHjFjUiJjOjEjFjYhQfEXzMjHjFjUiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFhRfVhJfCRBVEfEffnfffABnhEnbyBn0
ABJ2jEBnAEXhPfVDfyBRBCzBhLhSEXhQfEXhRfVhJfyBRBVEfyBffnfnndBffAVEfEAVhMfDByBWAEX
zGjIjBjTiLjFjZhTfVhJfCRBEjZfRBFeMjUjBjSjHjFjUiMjBjZjFjSjTffffb2jIBn0AEJ2jIBnASh
GBEjhHfntnftJ2jJBnAEXzLjQjVjUiQjSjPjQjFjSjUjZhUfVhGfBRCEjgdfRBFeEiQjSjQjSffEjgd
fRBFeEiJjUjNiJffffJ2jKBnAEXhIfVhGfBRDEjgdfRBFeEiMjZjShAffEjgdfRBFeEiPjSjEjOffEj
gdfRBFeEiUjSjHjUffffg2jMBbyBn0ACJ2jNBnAXhOfjHfJ2jOBnAEXhPfVDfARBCzBhNhVEXzKjHjF
jUiJjOjUjFjHjFjShWfEjhKfRBVhGfBffRBEjgdfRBFeEiJjUjNiJffffnndBffABnhEnbyBn0ABJ2j
RBnAEXhPfVDfyBRBEXhWfEjhKfRBVhGfyBffRBEjgdfRBFeEiJjUjNiJffffffZ2jVBnAVDf0AFE4E0
AiAhJ4C0AiAhG4B0AiAD40BiAhM4D0AiAAFAzUjHjFjUiTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEiMjBjZjFjSjTiJjEjYh
XA2jWBM2jYBbyBn0ABa2kGBb2kHBn0AHJ2kHBnAShJBEjgbfntnftJ2kIBnAShGCEjhHfntnftJ2kJB
nAEXzIjQjVjUiJjOjEjFjYhYfVhGfCRCEjgdfRBFeEiMjZjShAffQCfVzDjJjEjYhZfGVEfAffJ2kKB
nAEXzMjQjVjUiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFhafVhJfBRCEjgdfRBFeEjOjVjMjMffVhGfCffO2kLBb2kMBn0
AEJ2kMBnASzTjJjEjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjShbDEjZfRBFeRjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPj
OiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjSffnftJ2kNBnASzXjJjEjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjSiUjZjQjFh
cEEjZfRBFeVjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOiNjPjEjJjGjJjFjSiUjZjQjFffnftJ2kOBnASzQjJjEjBjEjEi
UjPiTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOhdFEjZfRBFeOjBjEjEiUjPiTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjOffnftJ2kPBnAEXhIfV
hJfBRDVhbfDVhcfEVhdfFffACzBheheVEfAnndAnJ2kRBnAEXzKjQjVjUiCjPjPjMjFjBjOhffVhJfB
RCEjgdfRBFeEiNjLiWjTffVzHjWjJjTjJjCjMjFiAfHffJ2kSBnAEjhBfRDEjgdfRBFeEjTjMjDjUff
VhJfBXhCfjhDfffAVEf0AXVfVhZfGByBWAIE40BiAhJ4B0AiAhG4C0AiAiA4B0AhAhb4D0AiAhc4E0A
iAhd4F0AiAhZ40BhACGABA2kUBSJBnASDyBEjhXfnfnftJCnASzDjEjPjDiByBXHfjIfnftJFnASzGi
ViJifjSjFjTiCyBChSChSnXVfVDfyBegfjEjJjBjMjPjHjbhAjUjFjYjUhahAhHiUjSjBjOjTjGjPjS
jNhAiFjBjDjIhAhInnne2jOIhAiMjBjZjFjSjThAiTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEhJhHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSj
FjEiTjJjajFhaibhNhRhMhAhNhRidhMKJJJJJjTjDjBjMjFhahAiQjBjOjFjMhAjbhAjUjFjYjUhahH
iTjDjBjMjFhHhMhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhahHj
DjFjOjUjFjShHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjHjIjUhHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjF
jEiTjJjajFhaibhThUhQhMhQidhMKJJJJJJjDjPjOjUjSjPjMjThahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjO
jUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjDjPjMjVjNjOhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjHjIjUhHh
MKJJJJJJJjIjPjSjJjajPjOjUjBjMhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjP
jXhHhMhAjNjBjSjHjJjOjThaibhShQhMhVhMhRhQhMhVidKJJJJJJJJjMjBjCjFjMhahAiTjUjBjUjJ
jDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiXjJjEjUjIhahHjdhMKJJJJJJJJjTjMjJjEjFjShahAiTjMjJjEjF
jShAjbjWjBjMjVjFhahRhQhQhMhAjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFhahThQhQhMhAjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFhahQhMh
AjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhRhVhQhMhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJJJjUjYjUhahAiFjEjJjUiUj
FjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHhRhQhQhFhHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFjSjThahAhVjdhMKJJJJJJJjdhMKJ
JJJJJJjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjMhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMh
AjNjBjSjHjJjOjThaibhShQhMhVhMhRhQhMhVidKJJJJJJJJjMjBjCjFjMhahAiTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFj
YjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiIjFjJjHjIjUhahHjdhMKJJJJJJJJjTjMjJjEjFjShahAiTjMjJjEjFjShAj
bjWjBjMjVjFhahRhQhQhMhAjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFhahThQhQhMhAjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFhahQhMhAjQjS
jFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhRhVhQhMhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJJJjUjYjUhahAiFjEjJjUiUjFjYjU
hAjbjUjFjYjUhahHhRhQhQhFhHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFjSjThahAhVjdhMKJJJJJJJjdhMKJJJJJJ
jdKJJJJJjdKJJJJJKJJJJJKJJJJJjSjPjUjBjUjFhahAiQjBjOjFjMhAjbhAjUjFjYjUhahHiSjPjUj
BjUjFhHhMhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhahHjDjFjO
jUjFjShHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjHjIjUhHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTj
JjajFhaibhThUhQhMhQidhMKJJJJJJjBjOjHjMjFhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPj
OhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjNjBjSjHjJjOjThaibhShQhMhVhMhRhQhMhVidhMKJJJJJJJjMjBjCjFjMha
hAiTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiBjOjHjMjFhahHjdKJJJJJJJjTjMjJjEjFjShahAi
TjMjJjEjFjShAjbjWjBjMjVjFhahQhMhAjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFhahThWhQhMhAjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFha
hNhThWhQhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhRhVhQhMhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJJjUjYjUhahAi
FjEjJjUiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHhQ2maChHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFjSjThahAhVjdhMKJJJJJ
JjdhMKJJJJJjdKJJJJJKJJJJJKJJJJJjBiQjPjJjOjUhahAiQjBjOjFjMhAjbhAjUjFjYjUhahHiUjS
jBjOjTjGjPjSjNjBjUjJjPjOhAiQjPjJjOjUhHhMhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHh
MhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhahHjDjFjOjUjFjShHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjDjFjO
jUjFjShHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhThUhQhMhQidhMKJJJJJJjDjPjOjUjSjPjMha
hAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSj
FjOhahHjMjFjGjUhHhMhAjNjBjSjHjJjOjThaibhShQhMhVhMhRhQhMhVidhMKJJJJJJJjUjYjUhahA
iTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiQjMjBjDjFjNjFjOjUhahHjdhMKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJjd
KJJJJJKJJJJJKJJJJJjPjQjUjJjPjOjThahAiQjBjOjFjMhAjbhAjUjFjYjUhahHiPjQjUjJjPjOjTh
HhMhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhahHjGjJjMjMhHhM
hAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjMjFjGjUhHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhTh
UhQhMhQidhMKJJJJJJjDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYjFjThahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOh
ahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjMjFjGjUhHhMhAjNjBjSjHjJjOjThaib
hShQhMhVhMhRhQhMhVidhMKJJJJJJJjTjDjBjMjFiTjUjZjMjFjThahAiDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYhAjbjUj
FjYjUhahHiTjDjBjMjFhAiTjUjZjMjFjThHhMhAjWjBjMjVjFhahAjUjSjVjFjdhMKJJJJJJJjMjPjD
jLiTjDjBjMjFhahAiDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiDjPjOjTjUjSjBjJjOhAiQjSjPjQjPj
SjUjJjPjOjThHhMhAjWjBjMjVjFhahAjUjSjVjFjdhMKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJjdKJJJJJKJJJJJKJJJJJj
CjVjUjUjPjOjThahAiHjSjPjVjQjbhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjH
jOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjHjIjUhHhMhAjNjBjSjHjJjOjThaibhQhMhVhMhRhQhMhVidhMhAK
JJJJJJjBjCjPjVjUifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhahAhHhfhHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSj
SjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhThQhMhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJjQjSjFjWjJjFjXifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOh
AjbjUjFjYjUhahAhHiQjSjFjWjJjFjXhHjdhMKJJJJJJjHjSjPjVjQhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbhAjNjBj
SjHjJjOjThaibhThQhMhNhRhMhNhRhMhNhRidhMKJJJJJJJjPjLifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjb
jUjFjYjUhahHiPiLhHjdhMKJJJJJJJjDjBjOjDjFjMifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUh
ahHiDjBjOjDjFjMhHjdhMKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJjdKJJJJjdnftghZbyBn0AFJhanASzBjXiDyBEjzGiXj
JjOjEjPjXiEfRBViCfyBftnffJhcnASzGjBiQjPjJjOjUiFyBEXzDjBjEjEiGfXzHjDjPjOjUjSjPjM
iHfXiFfViDfyBRDFeMjEjSjPjQjEjPjXjOjMjJjTjUjzJjVjOjEjFjGjJjOjFjEiIfARLFeIiUjPjQh
AiMjFjGjUFeKiUjPjQhAiDjFjOjUjFjSFeJiUjPjQhAiSjJjHjIjUFeBhNFeLiNjJjEjEjMjFhAiMjF
jGjUFeNiNjJjEjEjMjFhAiDjFjOjUjFjSFeMiNjJjEjEjMjFhAiSjJjHjIjUFeBhNFeLiCjPjUjUjPj
NhAiMjFjGjUFeNiCjPjUjUjPjNhAiDjFjOjUjFjSFeMiCjPjUjUjPjNhAiSjJjHjIjUfffnftJiDnAB
XzNjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFiJfViFfyBARCFdlUFdyBfnfJiEnABXzJjTjFjMjFjDjUjJjPjO
iKfViFfyBndFfbiHn0AKJiHnASSyBXzGjTjMjJjEjFjSiLfXJfXzIjDjPjOjUjSjPjMjTiMfXzFjTjD
jBjMjFiNfViDfyBnftJiInASzOjIjPjSjJjajPjOjUjBjMifjUjYjUiOyBXzDjUjYjUiPfXJfXiMfXi
NfViDfyBnftJiKnASTyBXiLfXKfXiMfXiNfViDfyBnftJiLnASzMjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjMifjUjYjUiQy
BXiPfXKfXiMfXiNfViDfyBnftJiOnASzIjBjOjHjMjFifjTjMiRyBXiLfXNfXMfViDfyBnftJiPnASz
JjBjOjHjMjFifjUjYjUiSyBXiPfXNfXMfViDfyBnftJiRnASzMjMjPjDjLiTjDjBjMjFifjDjCiTyBX
zJjMjPjDjLiTjDjBjMjFiUfXzKjDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYjFjTiVfXzHjPjQjUjJjPjOjTiWfViDfyBnftJ
iSnASzOjTjDjBjMjFiTjUjZjMjFjTifjDjCiXyBXOfXiVfXiWfViDfyBnftJiUnASzJjBjCjPjVjUif
jCjUjOiYyBXiYfXzHjCjVjUjUjPjOjTiZfViDfyBnftJiVnASzLjQjSjFjWjJjFjXifjCjUjOiayBXi
afXiZfViDfyBnftABnhEnbyBn0ABJibnAEjzFjBjMjFjSjUibfRBjhEfffJienABXzHjPjOiDjMjJjD
jLicfViTfyBNyBnAMiebyBn0ABOifbjAn0ACJjAnABXRfjTfXRfjSfnfJjBnABXzEjUjFjYjUidfjiQ
fXidfjiOfnfACWXRfjTfXRfjSfnnbjDn0ACJjDnABXRfjSfXRfjTfnfJjEnABXidfjiOfXidfjiQfnf
0DCCjGnfJjKnABXzKjPjOiDjIjBjOjHjJjOjHiefVSfyBNyBnAMjKbyBn0ADJjLnABXRfezEjUjIjJj
TiffEXzFjSjPjVjOjEjAfjQfRBXRfeiffffnfJjMnABXidfjiOfChSXRfeiffnneBhFnfOjObjPn0AC
JjPnABXRfjTfXRfjSfnfJjQnABXidfjiQfXidfjiOfnfAXRfjiTfn0DCCjSnfJjUnABXzIjPjOiDjIj
BjOjHjFjBfViOfyBNyBnAMjUbyBn0AHJjVnABXidfeiffEjzIjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUjCfRBXidfeifff
fnfOjXbyjYn0ABJjYnABXidfeiffXRfjSfnfAEjzFjJjTiOjBiOjDfRBXidfeiffffnOjbnACheXidf
eiffXzIjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFjEfjSfnnnOjfbykAn0ABJkAnABXidfeiffXzIjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFjFf
jSfnfACWXidfeiffXjFfjSfnnnJkDnABXRfjSfXidfeiffnfJkEnABXidfeiffChSnnneBhFntOkGbk
Hn0ACJkHnABXRfjTfXRfjSfnfJkInABXidfjiQfXidfjiOfnfAXRfjiTfn0DCCkKnfJkOnABXiefVTf
yBNyBnAMkObyBn0ADJkPnABXRfeiffEXjAfjQfRBXRfeiffffnfJkQnABXidfjiQfChSXRfeiffnneB
hFnfOkSbkTn0ACJkTnABXRfjSfXRfjTfnfJkUnABXidfjiOfXidfjiQfnfAXRfjiTfn0DCCkWnfJkYn
ABXjBfViQfyBNyBnAMkYbyBn0AHJkZnABXidfeiffEjjCfRBXidfeiffffnfOkbbykcn0ABJkcnABXi
dfeiffXRfjTfnfAEjjDfRBXidfeiffffnOkfnACheXidfeiffXjEfjTfnnnOlDbylEn0ABJlEnABXid
feiffXjFfjTfnfACWXidfeiffXjFfjTfnnnJlHnABXRfjTfXidfeiffnfJlInABXidfeiffChSnnneB
hFntOlKblLn0ACJlLnABXRfjSfXRfjTfnfJlMnABXidfjiOfXidfjiQfnfAXRfjiTfn0DCClOnfJlSn
ABXiefViRfyBNyBnAMlSbyBn0ACJlTnABXRfeiffEXjAfjQfRBXRfeiffffnfJlUnABXidfjiSfChSX
RfeiffnneB2maCnf0DCClVnfJlXnABXjBfViSfyBNyBnAMlXbyBn0AGJlYnABXidfeiffEjjCfRBXid
feiffffnfOlabylbn0ABJlbnABXidfeiffXRfjiRfnfAEjjDfRBXidfeiffffnOlebylfn0ABJlfnAB
XidfeiffXjEfjiRfnfACheXidfeiffXjEfjiRfnnnOmCbymDn0ABJmDnABXidfeiffXjFfjiRfnfACW
XidfeiffXjFfjiRfnnnJmGnABXRfjiRfXidfeiffnfJmHnABXidfeiffChSnnneB2maCnt0DCCmInfJ
mNnABXicfViYfyBNyBnAMmNbyBn0ABJmQnAEjibfRBFeiOiUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNhAiFjBjDjIhAhSh
OhRKiDjSjFjBjUjFjEhAjCjZhAiLjBjNjJjMhAiLjIjBjEjFjZjFjWhAhIiAjEjBjSjLjXjBjSjLhJK
jCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjDjPjNKlJhAhShQhRhVff0DCCmRnfJmWnASLyBXzMiNiJiEiEiMiFiDiF
iOiUiFiSjGfjzOiBjOjDjIjPjSiQjPjTjJjUjJjPjOjHfnftJmYnASzPjBiQjPjJjOjUiQjPjTjJjUj
JjPjOjTjIyBARLXzHiUiPiQiMiFiGiUjJfjjHfXzJiUiPiQiDiFiOiUiFiSjKfjjHfXzIiUiPiQiSiJ
iHiIiUjLfjjHfFeAXzKiNiJiEiEiMiFiMiFiGiUjMfjjHfXjGfjjHfXzLiNiJiEiEiMiFiSiJiHiIiU
jNfjjHfFeAXzKiCiPiUiUiPiNiMiFiGiUjOfjjHfXzMiCiPiUiUiPiNiDiFiOiUiFiSjPfjjHfXzLiC
iPiUiUiPiNiSiJiHiIiUjQfjjHffnftJnKnABXjBfViFfyBNyBnAMnKbyBn0ABJnLnABjLfQCfjjIfX
zFjJjOjEjFjYjRfXiKfeiffnf0DCCnMnfJnRnASzOjQjSjFjWjJjFjXiDjMjJjDjLjFjEjSyBncfftJ
nUnABXicfViafyBNyBnAMnUbyBn0AKOnVbynWn0ABJnWnABXzSjBjDjUjJjWjFiIjJjTjUjPjSjZiTj
UjBjUjFjTfjiBfQCfXzNjIjJjTjUjPjSjZiTjUjBjUjFjTjUfjiBfChVXVfXjUfjiBfnndCnfAjjSfn
JnZnABjzFjQjSjFjWiIjVfEjjCfRBXidfjiOfffnfJnanABjzFjQjSjFjWiXjWfEjjCfRBXidfjiQff
fnfJnbnABjzJjQjSjFjWiBjOjHjMjFjXfEjjCfRBXidfjiSfffnfJncnABjzPjQjSjFjWiTjDjBjMjF
iTjUjZjMjFjTjYfXRfjiXfnfJndnABjzIjQjSjFjWiBiQjPjTjZfjLfnfJnfnAEXzOjTjVjTjQjFjOj
EiIjJjTjUjPjSjZjafXHfjIfRCFehfibiLiBiNidhAiUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNhAiFjBjDjIhAiTjDjSj
JjQjUhAhIiMjFjBjSjOhAjNjPjSjFhahAjIjUjUjQhahPhPjCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjDjPjNhJFe
kZjUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNiFjBjDjIhIjTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEiMjBjZjFjSjThMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUh
IjIjPjSjJjajPjOjUjBjMifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjM
ifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjBjOjHjMjFifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjTj
DjBjMjFiTjUjZjMjFjTifjDjChOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAjBjOjDjIjPjSiQjPjTjJjUjJjPjOhJffJ2BBnA
EjBfRCjDfFcfffJ2CBnABjjSfnctfJ2EBnAEXzHjSjFjGjSjFjTjIjbfjIfnf0DCC2FBnfO2JBby2KB
n0ABO2KBb2NBn0ACO2NBb2VBn0ADJ2VBnABXjTfViBfyBQCfXjUfViBfyBChVXVfXjUfViBfyBnndCn
fJ2WBnAEXjafXHfjIfRCFehfibiLiBiNidhAiUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNhAiFjBjDjIhAiTjDjSjJjQjUh
AhIiMjFjBjSjOhAjNjPjSjFhahAjIjUjUjQhahPhPjCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjDjPjNhJFekZjUjS
jBjOjTjGjPjSjNiFjBjDjIhIjTjFjMjFjDjUjFjEiMjBjZjFjSjThMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjIjPj
SjJjajPjOjUjBjMifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjMifjUjY
jUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjBjOjHjMjFifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjTjDjBjMj
FiTjUjZjMjFjTifjDjChOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAjBjOjDjIjPjSiQjPjTjJjUjJjPjOhJffJ2YBnAEjBfRC
VDfyBFcfffAUzChGhGjcVjSfyBUzCjcjcjdUjdUjdUjdCzChBhdjeVjVfyBEjjCfRBXidfViOfyBffn
nCjeVjWfyBEjjCfRBXidfViQfyBffnnnnCjeVjXfyBEjjCfRBXidfViSfyBffnnnnCjeVjYfyBXRfVi
XfyBnnnnCjeVjZfyBVLfyBnnnnnnnO2gbBb2gcBn0ACJ2gcBnAEXjafXHfjIfRCFehfibiLiBiNidhA
iUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNhAiFjBjDjIhAiTjDjSjJjQjUhAhIiMjFjBjSjOhAjNjPjSjFhahAjIjUjUjQh
ahPhPjCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjDjPjNhJFekZjUjSjBjOjTjGjPjSjNiFjBjDjIhIjTjFjMjFjDjU
jFjEiMjBjZjFjSjThMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjIjPjSjJjajPjOjUjBjMifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJh
MhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhIjWjFjSjUjJjDjBjMifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjUhI
jBjOjHjMjFifjUjYjUhOjUjFjYjUhJhMhAjTjDjBjMjFiTjUjZjMjFjTifjDjChOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAj
BjOjDjIjPjSiQjPjTjJjUjJjPjOhJffJ2geBnAEjBfRCVDfyBFcfffAhzBhBjfVjSfyBnACzChdhdkA
EXzEjTjIjPjXkBfViDfyBnfnndBby2hFBn0ABO2hFBby2hGBn0ABJ2hGBnABXjTfViBfyBQCfXjUfVi
BfyBChVXVfXjUfViBfyBnndCnfAVjSfyBnACheXVfVDfyBnndBby2hKBn0ABJ2hKBnAEjibfRBFehFi
PjVjDjIhBKiQjMjFjBjTjFhAjTjFjMjFjDjUhAjNjPjSjFhAjUjIjBjOhAhRhAjMjBjZjFjSffAXiQ4
I0AiAiR4J0AiAiS4K0AiAiT4L0AiAiX4M0AiAiY4N0AiAia4O0AiAL4P0AiAjI4Q0AiAjS4R0AiAjV4
S0AiAjW4T0AiAjX4U0AiAjY4V0AiAjZ4W0AiAiD4C0AiAD40BiAiC4D0AiAiF4E0AiAS4F0AiAiO4G0
AiAT4H0AiAiB4B0AiAAXACByB
```

Comment: For those who are new to using scripts. Note that once a script is put into the photoshop scripts folder, you can set a hotkey to launch the script. I highly recommend doing that with this script.

Comment: The author updated his script to work with CC2014/2015, available [here](http://blog.darkwark.com/transformEach21/) :)

Comment: Buggy script. Makes your photoshop slow. Test if by duplicating a layer, it'll snap for a while with this script loaded.

Comment: @user2876479, do you mean to say your PS freezes when you use it? You might want to try it with a fewer layers. Scripts that deal with hundreds of layers tend to freeze PS. Though if that is what is happening, PS usually pulls through eventually when the process is done. I just tried it in CC 2019 and didn't have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Can..
open (windows) from menus, record a new action, do your steps on a layer, stop the recording of action, select all layers you want to do same action on, select your new recorded action from actions list.

with regards

Answer (score 0):

The Photoshop script isn't working for me, so I thought I'd list something that isn't quite complete automation but works pretty fast.

Create an action called "Scale 25%":
Decrease layer size by 25%. Stop.

Create another action called "Choose next layer":
Select one layer down: alt [
...AND select action "Decrease layer size by 25%" and play. Stop.

---

There, done! Now, place all layers that you want to decrease by 25% into one group. Choose the top layer.

Run the "Scale by 25%" action one time.
Then run the "Choose next layer" action over and over. Just keep pressing the play button on the action and watch the layers shrink around their own anchor point until you're done.

It may not be complete automation, but clicking 1 button over and over is fast. I just did it to hundreds of layers in about 1 minute.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. 3 steps:

1. Select all layers you would like to scale down
2. Go **Edit** → ***Free Transform***
3. Use the Free Transform panel

   - Or scale it down by hand, using the handles (press shift to maintain the proportion)

Comment: I already knew that, but this way they scale relative to one, common anchor point. I wish to scale them each around theit respective anchor points. I'm looking for a way to automate that.