# How to get all images in all layers to trim to center and resize canvas in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, batch-processing

Let me try to explain this:

- I have a canvas that is 400 X 400
- I have 3 layers
- Layer I image is 100 X 100
- Layer II image is 200 X 200
- Layer III image is 300 X 300

I want ALL images in all layers to convert to 100 X 100 sized and have canvas[image] convert to 100 X 100

In other words, I multiple trim/resize as a batch, is this even possible?

Comment: It's doable. Perhaps the simplest way to do this would be to first export the layers as files and then batch process those layers as individual image files. So you could use `File > Scripts > Export layers to files...` export as psd. Then basically process the the images with either `File > Automate > Batch...` or `File > Scripts > Image processor...`. You'd then probably want to use an action in this batch process to resize the canvas: `Image > Resize canvas...` and perhaps something else...

Comment: If you're willing to try a script, does this answer help you? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38985/92036

Answer (score 1):

Select the layer that are bigger than 100px and resize it to 100px:
**Window > Properties**

set the bounding box to W: 100 and H: 100

then select all layers, **right click > Quick Export as PNG** to save all the layers as .png. The canvas size and image position doesnt matter, as long as you have it to 100x100px and use **Quick Export as PNG** the output will be the size of the layer.

[image]

Comment: There is no Windows>Properties option, using Photoshop CS5

Comment: Oh, try pressing Ctrl + T, you can resize manually or change width and height on top bar. Usually it's set to 100%, you can change % by px.