# How can I resize a group of images with reference to their center?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I have a group of a few hundred objects in specific locations, and they are all slightly too small.

I would like to resize all of them at once. However, resizing the whole group drags the items out of their original location to respect the increasing change in empty space between the objects too.

I don't want this. I want each object to increase in size, perhaps 130%, with respect to it's original position. I don't mind if the objects grow so large they begin to overlap.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize multiple layers around their respective anchor points](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38985/2332)

Comment: @Joonas I believe it does. Thank you very much. Now I just have to work out how to use scripts!

Comment: A real quick way is to drag the file to the Photoshop icon.  **Mac:** Drag the .jsx file to the PS icon in the Dock. **Windows:** Drag the .jsx file to the PS icon in the taskbar but hold down `shift` when you let go. — This method is obviously not so great if it's a script you want to use often. So maybe you need to use the traditional way and put it in the script folder instead. — If you want to get crazy with it, you can also use third party applications to launch the script: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63446/2332 - This talks about AI, but it works just the same for PS.

Comment: I personally use Alfred on Mac and this workflow: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-Illustrator-Script-Launcher-Using-Alfred — 
By the way, this transform each script resizes every selected layer individually. If you're selecting groups with the `Shift` modifier, it also select the layers between the groups, which I don't think you'd want... but you can circumvent that by then collapsing any group by holding down `Cmd` or `Ctrl`. That undoes the selection for all the inner layers. — If you can't do that, you have to just select the group layers one by one using `Cmd` or `Ctrl`.